# Doctrine2 Entities Generation with YML ContextErrorException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm facing an issue with Entities generation on Doctrine2 and YML (*.orm.yml) files. The schema files are to generate a set of entities having one-To-many relationships among them .
However, upon using the `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleName` it raise the following error:     `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: Illegal string offset 'strategy'`.  Some of the entities to be created contains an ID (int) field that is to be autogenerated (see below).  You may found [here](http://pastebin.com/S46w84bQ) the full stack trace of the error

```html
Agape\AgapeEPSBundle\Entity\Parent:
    type: entity
    table: parent
    id:
        id:
            type: int
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        nom:
            type: string
            length: 250
            nullable: false
        prenoms:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: false
        date_de_naiss:
            type: date
        telephone:
            type: string
            length: 250
            nullable: false     
        email:
            type: string
            length: 250
        date_of_creation:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
    manyToOne:
        etablissement:
            targetEntity: etablissement
            inversedBy: parents
<!-- Typo here !! -->
            joinColumn:
                name: etablissement_id
                referencedColumnName: rne
    oneToMany:
        candidats:
            targetEntity: candidat
            mappedBy: parent
```

Comment: Just replace the `int` by `integer`

Comment: Thanks for the reply and highlighting this. However, it's still not working and generating the same error.

Comment: erf ok. Did you copy/paste the yaml from somewhere ? It's very frequent that yaml file has problem on parsing when you copy/paste the file because of indents. Try to reindent everything manually with 4 or 2 spaces.

Comment: Nope, the file wasn't copy/pasted from somewhere i typed and indented them all  ,i also validated them against the following YAML validators http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator ; yamllint.com .

Answer (score 0):

```
type: int
generator:
trategy: AUTO
```

This line must be aligned

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but based on the resource found here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys the indentation should not be the source of the error. But i did try your recommendation but i still get the same error.

Comment: i am sorry , this is wrong example,but i still think error is YML,http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html

Comment: True, there seem to be problem with the YAML driver but i can just figure it out.The ORM files being used are fully qualified.